# Experience Builder: Knowledge Object Page? (and NavigationMixin issue)

Tags: community, experience-builder-page, digital-experience

`Knowledge` is not an option to create a **New Object Page** in the Experience builder? Any idea why/where it might be?

[image]

Currently using the Generic object page for knowledge articles, but has presented other issues when attempting to navigate to the record pages.

```js
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
  type: 'standard__knowledgeArticlePage',
  attributes: {
    urlName: 'knowledge-article-variable-here',
  },
})
```

Above silently fails and does nothing

```js
this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
  type: 'standard__knowledgeArticlePage',
  attributes: {
    urlName: 'knowledge-article-variable-here',
  },
}).then((url) => console.log('url? ', url))
```

This returns `undefined`

The Knowledge articles are visible to guest users. The generic Object Page displays them without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not available as an Object page but I believe that is by design because experience sites are designed to work with knowledge to show articles. I'm not clear on why you want to build a Object page based on Knowledge when access to articles and topics is built into digital experience.

The only thing that I can think of you don't have easy access to would be list views for articles, but that functionality is replicated by topics/topic catalog/topic detail pages.

[This article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_knowledge_access.htm&type=5) makes it pretty clear how Knowledge functions in an experience site. I might be missing something obvious, but I don't know what you would gain by creating a Knowledge Object page.

Comment: Ah, its under `Standard Pages` instead. Would be nice if Object Pages could use a similar `urlName` type field for cleaner urls without salesforce Ids. ah well, can't win them all. Thanks